# Confusion about a random process

Tags: probability, random-variables, random, stationary-processes

Let $X(t)$ be a random process such that:
$$
X(t) = \begin{cases}
t & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2} \\
2-at & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{cases},
$$
where $a$ is a constant.
I need to find the value of $a$ for which $X(t)$ is a wide-sense stationary process. I have made the following definition of the random process:
$$
\begin{equation}
X(t) = \alpha t + (1-\alpha)(2-at),
\end{equation}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $p=q=0.5$.

For mean, we have
$$
E[X(t)] = \frac{t + 2-at}{2}.
$$
For the autocorrelation function,
$$
\begin{align*}
R_X(t_1,t_2) &= E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]\\
&=E[(\alpha t_1 + (1-\alpha)(2-at_1))\times(\alpha t_2 + (1-\alpha)(2-at_2))]\\
&=E[\alpha^2 t_1 t_2 + (1-\alpha)^2(2-at_1)(2-at_2)]\\
&=\frac{t_1 t_2}{2} + \frac{4-a(t_1+at_2)+a^2 t_1 t_2}{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$
As clear from the above equation, there is no value of $a$ for which autocorrelation function is a function of time difference $t_2-t_1$.

My confusion starts from the way we define autocorrelation function as above in so many text books. The above-mentioned definition shows that we sample the ensemble at two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ to get two random variables. The two random variables $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ are (possibly different) functions of the same random variable $\alpha$. My question is why do we need to take the same random variable $\alpha$ at two time instants? It is like saying that if we know $X(t_1)$, we can figure out $X(t_2)$ right away. Shouldn't it be like that at $t_1$ we should take $\alpha_1$ and at $t_2$ we should take $\alpha_2$, where both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are Bernoulli with $p=0.5$.

I can describe the confusion like the following as well. When we sample the random process at two time instants, we get two random variables $A = X(t_1)$ and $B = X(t_2)$, where
$$
A = \begin{cases}
t_1 & \text{ with probability 0.5} \\
2-at_1 & \text{ with probability 0.5} \\
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
B = \begin{cases}
t_2 & \text{ with probability 0.5} \\
2-at_2 & \text{ with probability 0.5} \\
\end{cases}.
$$
To calculate $E[AB]$, we need to take the cases into account where $A=t_1$ and $B=2-at_2$, and $A=2-at_1$ and $B=t_2$. Both of these cases do not appear in the calculation of ensemble autocorrelation function $R_X(t_1,t_2)$. Why do I get to take the two cases into account when I use the formulation in terms of $A$ and $B$, and these two cases do not appear when I calculated $R_X(t_1, t_2)$ using the formulation with $\alpha$ as discussed in the start of the problem?

Comment: Your definition of the random process in terms of a single Bernoulli random variable $\alpha$ is only correct if the choice between $t$ and $2-at$ is made *once* for all $t$.  If (as I believe is intended) the choice is made independently for each $t$, then you need a different Bernoulli random variable $\alpha(t)$ for each $t$, such that $\alpha(t_1)$ and $\alpha(t_2)$ are independent when $t_1\neq t_2$.  This reformulation makes everything come out right.

Comment: You only computed part of the autocorrelation.  It should be $E[(A(u)-E[A(u)])(A(v)-E[A(v)])]$.  For your original definition of the process,  you can actually find a value $a$ for which this does not depend on $u$ or $v$.

Comment: No, your discussion at the end of your question starts down a wrong path.  It is not correct to describe it like $A$ and $B$ as you suggest at the very end, because $A$ and $B$ are highly dependent.  You have $(A,B)=(t_1,t_2)$ with probability $1/2$ and $(A,B)=(2-a t_1, 2-at_2)$ with probability $1/2$.  The way the processes are defined, these are the only two outcomes. You correctly modeled the problem at the start, you just forgot to subtract the means.

Comment: As a hint about an easier way:  There is a value $a$ such that $X(t)-E[X(t)]$ does not even depend on $t$.  Also: I would not define a quantity $\alpha$ when in the same equation there is an $a$.  Makes it very easy to accidentally mix the two.

Comment: @mjqxxxx In my understanding, the choice for $\alpha$ is made only once, when we are considering the outcome of a random process. For a particular value of $\alpha$, $X(t)$ will give us one function of time, as intended from a random process.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to change this definition.

Comment: @Michael The ensemble correlation function is in fact $E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$. Please see [section 4.2 here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-017j-design-of-electromechanical-robotic-systems-fall-2009/course-text/MIT2_017JF09_ch04.pdf).

Comment: Who wrote those notes?  Section 4.2 gives two competing defintions.  The second one given is hte correct one.

Comment: @Michael I got it. Actually, the author of the notes mentioned it below that the first definition is only for the zero-mean case.

Comment: @Michael But I did read the definition without mean at some other places. Please see [here](http://postimg.org/image/ulbe8pyrb/). It has been taken from [Modern Digital and Analog Communication](http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Communication-Electrical-Computer-Engineering/dp/0195331451) by B. P. Lathi. I have looked around the text a lot, but couldn't find any qualification for zero-mean random processes.

Comment: @Michael Also, I have found the solution to the problem on Dr. John Gill 's [website (please see solution to problem 5](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee179/handouts/fsamp_sol.pdf). As you can see, the solution has taken the cross terms as well as the definition without means. Can you please comment if the solution is correct at taking the cross terms and about the definition of autocorrelation function? Thanks.

Comment: Here are my observations:  (i) I agree with your computation for $E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ up to your last line where I think you have a typo, the last term should be $\frac{4-2a(t_1+t_2)+a^2t_1t_2}{2}$. (ii) The solutions in the link you posted look wrong.  It looks like they are interpreting the problem as if $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ are independent, which is never stated in the problem, and which is certainly wrong if $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: Here is what I was saying before:  If you choose $a=-1$ then $X(t) = t+R$ where $Pr[R=0]=Pr[R=2]=1/2$. Then $E[X(t)]=t+1$ and $X(t)-E[X(t)]=R-1$, which does not depend on $t$.  So $E[(X(t)-E[X(t)])(E[X(u)-E[X(u)])]=E[(R-1)^2]$ does not depend on $t$ or $u$.  So with $a=-1$ you can say $X(t)-E[X(t)]$ is WSS.

Comment: In general:  If $E[X(t)]$ is constant with $t$, then $E[X(u)X(v)]$ depends only on $(u-v)$ if and only if $E[(X(u)-E[X(u)])(X(v)-E[X(v)])]$ depends only on $(u-v)$.  That is because $E[(X(u)-E[X(u)])(X(v)-E[X(v)])]=E[X(u)X(v)]-E[X(u)]E[X(v)]$.  For your process, the only way $E[X(t)]$ does not depend on $t$ is if $a=1$, in which case I get $E[X(u)X(v)]=2 + (uv-u-v)$, which cannot be written as a function of $(u-v)$.  So, as stated, there is no value of $a$ for which both $E[X(t)]$ does not depend on $t$ _and_ $E[X(t)X(v)]$ depends only on $(t-v)$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. That solves everything. Thank you for your time.